# On submitting the form in /reg.html, "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL." is shown

Tags: html, flask

I'm trying the following:

- Open homepage.html first
- If Register is selected, move to reg.html and enter the form. Submit the form and do some backend processing
- If Show is selected, print the registered APIs

The issue I'm facing is when I'm trying to fill the form and clicking on submit, it shows error 405. The further actions are thus void.

**homepage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>API Management Platform</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to API Management Platform</h1>
    <h2>You can register a new API and also see a list of already registered APIs</h2>
    Click on one of the following links!<br>
        1. <a href=reg>Register a new API</a><br>
        2. <a href=show>Display the list of APIs</a><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

**reg.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Register API</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to API Management Platform</h1>
    <h2>Please enter the API details</h2>
    <form action=. method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h3>API Data</h3>
      <p>Name: <input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
      <p>Description: <input type = "text" name = "Description" /></p>
      <p>Link: <input type = "url" name = "Link" /></p>
      <p>Developer: <input type = "text" name = "Developer" /></p>
      <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**show.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>List of APIs</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
      <br />  
      <div class="container" >
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1>Details</h1>
            <br />
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
               <tr>
                    <th>API ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                    <th>Developed By</th>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <br />  
   </body>
</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://extendsclass.com/api/json-storage/bin/dabbbff", function(data){
      var employee_data = '';
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        employee_data += '<tr>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+key+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.Description+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.Link+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<td>'+value.Developer+'</td>';
        employee_data += '<tr>';
      });
      $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
    });    
  });
</script>
```

**UI_AMP.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
import sys,os
from CMD_AMP import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route('/reg')
def regAPI():
    return render_template("reg.html")

@app.route('/show')
def getAPI():
    return render_template("show.html")

@app.route('/reg', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
        name = request.form['Name']
        print(name)
        desc = request.form['Description']
        print(desc)
        link = request.form['Link']
        print(link)
        devr = request.form['Developer']
        print(devr)
        apidev = {"Name": name, "Description": desc, "Link": link, "Developer": devr}
        insertAPI(apidev)
        return render_template("show.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: Your `action` is empty.

Comment: @ngShravil.py , it is not empty he has "." in it.

Comment: @AkibRhast , but it's just `action=.`, not `action='.'`.

Comment: @ngShravil.py You are right. However action=. is converted to action=''." automatically

Comment: Ohh, I was not aware of that. Thanks for letting me know. But, I think it's a bad practice.

Comment: Fully agree with you. Take a look at my answer. Also, I did not know about it till about 5 mins ago either. I spun up a quick instance to check it out. I will add this to my answer as well, another thing I have just found out. Is that "action = .", automatically routes to "/" . As such OPs 405 error, is actually being emitted by trying to access the home() function  @ngShravil.py

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that @ngShravil.py , let me know if I am missing something. Or got something wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the error is occurring is:

Because you have "action = . " in your form.

On page render that translates to " action = '.' " .

Which routes to :

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
```

Since the home function is not written to handle a POST method(default is GET). You get a "A 405 Method Not Allowed Error"

By default the if you do not assign a form action, when you submit the form it routes to the function/route of the page it is on.

In your reg.html, change this line

```
<form action=. method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form action="{{url_for('my_form_post')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I'm actually stuck with one more thing. So, I want the show.html file to get data from a local json file "API_Data.json" instead of the online link. It doesn't seem to work. The file easily gets data from the online json data store but fails to do so from a local file. The reg.html part is working fine.

Comment: Please make a separate question regarding that @HarshBhimrajka. Detailing, what you have tried. What is the expected out come, and what outcome you are currently getting. Just a side note tough look into how to use ajax to send data back and forth from front end to back end using flask